# SSRS Label Orientation

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2014, report-builder

I'm trying to print labels on a Zebra printer in SSRS 2014 and the orientation is coming out wrong. In report builder, I set the page size to 4.15 x 1.15 with correct margins. Also, in report builder, if I print it will typically come out the correct orientation (landscape), but occasionally I have to go into Page Setup, change the Orientation from Portrait to Landscape & back again to get it to print correctly (Not sure why it requires a Portrait orientation to print in Landscape in Report Builder. However, when I try to print from SSRS directly, it comes out in portrait and prints across several labels. I've done some research and saw recommendations to change the printer to print directly and bypass the print spooler, which I've attempted to no avail. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for my situation...

I went into Printer Settings & checked the "Always Use Driver Settings" under the "Override Application Default Settings." This caused the printer to always print in the correct orientation.